# Light rays in linearized General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity

In General Relativity, particles follow geodesics in space-time, obeying

$$\ddot x^a + \Gamma^a_{bc}\dot x^b\dot x^c=0,$$

where $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ are the Christoffel symbols, expressed in terms of the metric as

$$\Gamma^{a}_{bc} = \frac{1}{2}g^{ad}\left[g_{db,c}+g_{dc,b}-g_{bc,d}\right] $$

It's a standard result that in the linear regime $g_{\mu\nu}\sim \eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$, the geodesic equation for slowly moving (hence massive) particles reduces to Newton's law

$$\ddot x^j +\frac{1}{2} h_{00,j} =0,$$

meaning that we identify $h_{00}=-2\Phi$, where $\Phi$ is the gravitational potential. **My question is**: what is the analogous result for *light* i.e. particles travelling on null geodesics?

Comment: Don't you have to make other appeals to get your result, things like $v \ll c$, which enables you to say that $h_{00} \gg h_{ij}$ and similar conclusions about the christoffel symbols?

Comment: Yes, $v\ll c$ is what I meant by slowly moving. The other thing that I didn't mention is that $h_{\mu\nu}$ is usually assumed static: $h_{\mu\nu,0}=0$. However, this doesn't affect the form of the equation, only the identification of the potential (I think).

Comment: well, light obviously breaks those assumptions, but you can always look at the appoximate lensing formulae.

Comment: for a CONGRUENCE of geodesics, you have the Raychaudhari Equation

Comment: Jerry - do you know where I'd find a formula assuming only that the metric was close to Minkowski?

Comment: GRrocks - I'm not an expert so had to look up the Raychaudhari Equation, but I couldn't see how that helps me find the geodesics.